# cordova plugin cannot be properly installed in sencha touch

Tags: ios, cordova, extjs, plugins, sencha-touch

I am doing a sencha touch project with cordova.
they both are the lastest version:sencha touch 2.3.2, cordova is install by npm (sudo npm install -g cordova).
recently, i meet with a task which i need to do :Ext.device.Browser.open({url:url}).
but when i build native, it doesn't work, no broser shows and doesn't go to that url.("do i do this right?")
so i try to install the plugin:Inappbrowser.

> cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

and it shows that i installed it successfully

> Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" via plugin registry
>   Installing "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" for ios

but when i build the sencha project,it showes that:

> [INF] [shellscript] The following build commands failed: [INF]
>   [shellscript]     CompileC
>   build/fitnessmobile.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/fitnessmobile.build/Objects-normal/i386/CDVInAppBrowser.o
>   fitnessmobile/Plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/CDVInAppBrowser.m
>   normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>   [INF] [shellscript] (1 failure) [INF] [shellscript] Error:
>   /Users/hexue/Documents/projects/cuge/mobileapp/fitnessmobile/cordova/platforms/ios/cordova/build:
>   Command failed with exit code 65 [INF] [shellscript]     at
>   ChildProcess.whenDone
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
>   [INF] [shellscript]     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit
>   (events.js:98:17) [INF] [shellscript]     at maybeClose
>   (child_process.js:753:16) [INF] [shellscript]     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5) [ERR] The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/hexue/Documents/projects/cuge/mobileapp/fitnessmobile/.sencha/app/build-impl.xml:422:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /Users/hexue/Documents/projects/cuge/mobileapp/fitnessmobile/.sencha/app/cordova-impl.xml:118:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   jar:file:/Users/hexue/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.4.84/sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:608:
>   shellscript returned: 1

I need help!!!!

Comment: what command are you using to build the sencha project? Are you sure this is related to the plugin? What if you do a cordova build command from the cordova sub directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my provlem with init the crodova with a name;

> sencha cordova init XXXXXXXX

then add the plugin and then build.
no error!